# (Cucumber) Long Scenarios caused by pre-conditions

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I have to write a Gherkin scenario (C# Specflow) that has a large precondition before the test can be run and wondered what is the best approach. I have to complete multiple fields on a form and save it and record the form number created. I then have to do the exactly the same and create a second form.

The main purpose of the scenario is then to test a new function that associates the 2 completed forms.

I thought the best approach would be to do the pre-work as a background:

```
Background: Create Form Documents

Given I have logged into the System
And I have accessed the new <formType1> screen
When I complete all the mandatory <formType2> fields
And press the Save button
Then the new document number will be created

    Examples: 
    | formType1            | formType2            |
    | Building Certificate | Building Certificate |
    | Building Certificate | Building Certificate |
```

Then the scenario would be:

```
Scenario:
Given that I have accessed the "CHILD DOCUMENT NUMBER" screen
When I select "ASSOCIATE FORM DOCUMENTS" from the menu
And click the "ADD PARENT FORM DOCUMENT" button 
And I enter the "PARENT SAFETY DOCUMENT NUMBER" in the Search field
And click on the "SEARCH" button
And click the "SELECT" button   
Then the diagram should show "PARENT DOCUMENT NUMBER" as a parent of "CHILD DOCUMENT NUMBER"
```

I've read its a bad idea to pass data between scenarios, so is the best way just to lump all this into the one scenario which will in effect be doing the Background steps TWICE and then the main scenario? I'm trying to reuse existing steps and keep the scenarios short and concise. Any advice on the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Given I have two “Building Certificate” document numbers
When I associate the child document with the parent document
Then the parent safety document diagram should show the association
```

Within this, you’ll write the methods for creating the two documents, and assign the document numbers to an array variable.

When doing the associating, take the first to be the parent and associate it with the second.

This way, you’ll only have to complete one scenario.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I think I've misinterpreted how explicit the Gherkin should be, that looks straight forward enough. Cheers!